# Auctex preview: How to suppress opening a new window?

Tags: emacs, auctex, preview

I have emacs+gtk installed on Ubuntu11. I'm just new to Auctex but very interested in it. When completed my .tex document, command `C-c,C-c` compiles successfully. But repeating `C-c,C-c` yields option

`Command:(default View)`

So I prompt the default, which further yields

`View command: xdvi myfile.tex`.

It opens a new window. But I want it to be shown in a split window of myfile.tex so that I can edit and preview simultaneously. Any way to suppress the new window? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate? [Emacs + Auctex, Latex environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30527)

Answer (score 2):

No such thing is available.  While it is true that Emacs can by now display PDF files in a separate window, that is not really feasible for anything but quite small documents, like 1 or 2 pages.  You are missing a lot of features from a proper PDF viewer, though, and it has considerable memory impact depending on document size.  AUCTeX has no interface to that functionality, though you can just load the PDF file into a separate split window with `C-x 4 f`.

What AUCTeX does offer is [preview-latex](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/preview-latex): this will *not* create a split window.  Instead, selected graphical elements (typically images and math) will be replaced right *in* the buffer with graphics, and you can run the cursor (left/right) into them in order to get the source text back.  While its use is more limited than that of a full-bodied preview (for example, it is useless for checking the vertical page layout), access is much more direct and intuitive than even a split window.  Try `C-c C-p C-p` and/or the Preview menu.  It is conceivable that you need to follow installation instructions for making it available, depending on the version of AUCTeX installed on your system.